# Add a percentage discount based on customer total purchases sum in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce, cart, discount

In Woocommerce, I would like to set a percentage discount based on customer total purchases sum. For example if the total purchase sum **greater or equal to `200$`**, customer get **`5%` discount**.

So, I have first part of code for showing the total sum:

```
function get_customer_total_order() {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed' )
    ) );

    $total = 0;

    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
        $total += $order->get_total();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

And I would like to use my code with the code of this answer:
[Progressive discount based on cart total in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074070/progressive-discount-based-on-cart-total-in-woocommerce/46084950#46084950)

It there a way to use them both to set the discount based on total sum of all orders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is multiple ways to get customer's total purchases sum:

1) You could replace your first function using [`wc_get_customer_total_spent()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_customer_total_spent.html#471-479) dedicated Woocommerce function, but this function take all orders paid status *( which are "processing" and "completed")*.

2) You could also use this lighter SQL query based on a [similar source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#336-368) for "completed" order status only:

```
// Utililty function to get customer's total purchases sum
function get_customer_total_purchases_sum() {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Current user ID

    if( $current_user_id == 0 ) return 0; // we return zero if customer is not logged in

    global $wpdb;

    // return the SQL query (paid orders sum)
    return $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total' AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
    AND pm2.meta_value LIKE '$current_user_id'");
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

3) Or you can use your own question function code *(but it's heavier)*. It's up to you.

---

#### The percentage discount *(2 ways)*:

**1) A negative fee:**

The following code will set a percentage discount based on customer's total purchases sum *(using my function above)*:

```
// Percentage discount based on customer's total purchases sum
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'customer_purchases_total_sum_percentage_discount', 20, 1 );
function customer_purchases_total_sum_percentage_discount( $cart ){
    // Only for logged in user
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    ## 1. Get the customer's purchases total sum (and save it in WC sessions to avoid multiple queries

    // Check if it's saved in WC_Session
    $purchases_sum = WC()->session->get( 'purchases_sum' ); 
    // If not get it and save it
    if( empty($purchases_sum) ){ 
        // ==> HERE goes the function to get customer's purchases total sum
        $purchases_sum = get_customer_total_purchases_sum();
        // Save it in WC_Session
        WC()->session->set('purchases_sum', $purchases_sum); 
    }

    ## 2. Set the discount percentage based on customer's total purchases sum
    if( $purchases_sum >= 200 ){
        $percent =  5; // 5%
    }

    if( isset($percent) && $percent > 0){
        $discount = $cart->cart_contents_total * $percent / 100; // discount calculation
        // Set the discount (For discounts (negative fee) the taxes as always included)
        $cart->add_fee( __('Discount', 'woocommerce' ) . " (" . $percent . "%)", -$discount);
    }
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

---

**2) Auto adding a coupon code *(percentage discount)*:**

First you need to set a new coupon code (percentage discount type of 5%):

[image]

Then you will use the following code instead that will auto add a coupon code  based on customer's total purchases sum *(using my function above)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'customer_total_purchases_coupon_discount', 30, 1 );
function customer_total_purchases_coupon_discount( $cart ) {
    // Only for logged in user
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // HERE define your coupon code (in lowercase)
    $coupon_code = 'customersilver';

    ## 1. Get the customer's purchases total sum (and save it in WC sessions to avoid multiple queries

    // Check if it's saved in WC_Session
    $purchases_sum = WC()->session->get( 'purchases_sum' );
    // If not get it and save it
    if( empty($purchases_sum) ){
        // ==> HERE goes the function to get customer's purchases total sum
        $purchases_sum = get_customer_total_purchases_sum();
        // Save it in WC_Session
        WC()->session->set('purchases_sum', $purchases_sum);
    }

    ## 2. Auto applying or removing a coupon code (percentage discount coupon)

    // Apply the coupon if there is at least 2 units of "5 Reusable wet"
    if ( ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) && $purchases_sum >= 200 ) {
        $cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
    } elseif( $cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) && $purchases_sum < 200 ) {
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    }
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Comment: lovely solution :)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! It works exactly as I wanted it :)

Comment: @VasilisaSidorenkova Which ones did you choose? just a bit curious…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I just tested and adapted the first way of "The percentage discount (2 ways)". Thanks again, I wasn't sure if someone could help me so much!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec
Hi again! I would ask you for help... I want to return a result on page and use if/else.
So I'm trying to do:
` if purchases_sum >= 200  echo smth `
But it doesn't work:
`<?php if ( $purchases_sum >= 200 ): ?> 
 <h1>Something</h1> 
<?php else: ?>
   <h1>Another text</h1>
<?php endif ?>`

It shows me "another text' but result must be TRUE.

Comment: @VasilisaSidorenkova So something is wrong with `$purchases_sum`  variable calculated value… My code in this answer works. So It has to do with something else.