# Custom cart notice based on user total purchased amount in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, notice

I am trying to display a custom cart notice based on user total purchased amount in Woocommerce, based on this answer code:

[Add a percentage discount based on customer total purchases sum in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141772/add-a-percentage-discount-based-on-customer-total-purchases-sum-in-woocommerce/52141907#52141907)

It does not work as I would like.

For example if a customer has made 2 orders:

- First order is 200
- Second order is 122

So the total sum is 200 + 122 = 322. But I get a total of 200. 
What I am doing wrong?

This is the code that I use:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'vc' );

  function vc( ) {
// Only for logged in user
if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() )
    return;
$um = WC()->session->get( 'um' );
// If not get it and save it
if( empty($um) ){
    // ==> HERE goes the function to get customer's purchases total sum
    $um = get_customer_total_purchases_sum();
    // Save it in WC_Session
    WC()->session->set('um', $um);
}
 $vv=10000 - $um;
    if ( $um > 0 && $vv >0) {

    echo '<div class="woocommerce-message"><a href="' . get_permalink( 
       woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) . '" class="button wc-forward">Tiếp tục mua sắm</a>Bạn cần thêm ' . wc_price($vv) . ' để được.... </div>';
}
else { 
echo '......';
  }}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead *(I have revisited a bit `get_customer_total_purchases_sum()` function)*:

```
// Utililty function to get customer's total purchases sum
function get_customer_total_purchases_sum() {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Current user ID

    if( $current_user_id == 0 ) return 0; // we return zero if customer is not logged in

    global $wpdb;

    // return the SQL query (paid orders sum)
    return $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total' AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
    AND pm2.meta_value LIKE '$current_user_id'");
}

// Display a custom notice
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'total_purchase_custom_notification' );
function total_purchase_custom_notification( ) {

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && WC()->session->get( 'purchases_sum' ) ) {
        // We remove this session variable in thankyou page (if it still exist)
        WC()->session->__unset( 'purchases_sum' );
    }
    // On cart page we display a custom notice
    elseif( is_cart() ) {
        // Get customer's purchases total sum and set it in WC_Session
        if( ! WC()->session->get( 'purchases_sum' ) ){
            WC()->session->set('purchases_sum', get_customer_total_purchases_sum());
        }

        $total_purchases  = WC()->session->get( 'purchases_sum' );

        if ( $total_purchases == 0 ) return; // We exit (no purchases or non logged users)

        if ( ( 10000 - $total_purchases ) > 0 )
        {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf(
                '<a class="button alt wc-forward" style="float:right" href="%s">%s</a> ' .
                __( "You need an extra %s at all to get a...", "woocommerce" ),
                get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ),
                __( "Continue shopping", "woocommerce" ),
                strip_tags( wc_price( 10000 - $total_purchases ) )
            ), 'notice');
        }
        else
        {
            wc_add_notice( __( "......", "woocommerce"), 'notice' );
        }
    }
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Replaceable `add_action( 'template_redirect',` into `add_action( 'woocommerce_account_log-history_endpoint', `Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @LêNghĩa I don't catch… this code is for cart (or even checkout) but not using 'woocommerce_account_log-history_endpoint' hook that I have never used yet.

Comment: I added my custom account menu element.

Comment: `add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'xu', 40 );
function xu( $menu_links ){
 
 $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0,3 , true ) 
 + array( 'xu' => 'Xu của bạn' )
 + array_slice( $menu_links, 3, NULL, true );
 
 return $menu_links;
 
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_endpoint' );
function add_endpoint() {

 add_rewrite_endpoint( 'xu', EP_PAGES );
 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_xu_endpoint', 'xuxu' );
function xuxu() {
 
 
 
 //Custom cart notice based on user total purchased amount in Woocommerce
}
`

Comment: @LêNghĩa You should better ask a new question explaining clearly and detailed things… Code in comment zone is not readable and more without explanations.

Comment: [This is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121858/custom-messages-in-my-custom-account-menu-element-are-based-on-the-total-amoun)