# Progressive discount based on cart total and user roles in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I'm using *[Progressive discount based on cart total in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074070/progressive-discount-based-on-cart-total-in-woocommerce/46084950#46084950)* answer code to make some Woocommerce order total discounts *(see below)*. But I would like to make a discount based on user role, as each of my customer roles sees different prices.

I have some custom user roles: `wholesale_prices`, `wholesale_vat_exc`, and `distributor_prices`.

I want to make the code to work just for `wholesale_prices` and `wholesale_vat_exc` user roles, but not for `distributor_prices` *(as they must not see the discounts)*.

Here is my actual revisited code version:

```
// Order total discount

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'progressive_discount_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function progressive_discount_based_on_cart_total( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart_total = $cart_object->cart_contents_total; // Cart total

    if ( $cart_total >= 3000.00 && $cart_total < 5000.00 )
        $percent = 15; // 15%
    elseif ( $cart_total >= 1500.00 && $cart_total < 3000.00 )
        $percent = 10; // 10%
    elseif ( $cart_total >= 750.00 && $cart_total < 1500.00 )
        $percent =  5; // 5%
    else
        $percent = 0;

    if ( $percent != 0 ) {
        $discount =  $cart_total * $percent / 100;
        $cart_object->add_fee( "Bulk Order Discount ($percent%)", -$discount, true );
    }
}
```

How to make this code only available to `wholesale_prices` and `wholesale_vat_exc` user roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on *[Apply a discount for a specific user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889136/apply-a-discount-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce/54890439#54890439)* related answer, I use the WordPress conditional function [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) to target a specific user role…

So you need to use it in *[Progressive discount based on cart total in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074070/progressive-discount-based-on-cart-total-in-woocommerce/46084950#46084950)* answer code just like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'progressive_discount_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function progressive_discount_based_on_cart_total( $cart ) {
    // HERE we target other user roles than 'distributor_prices' (allowing guests)
    if ( current_user_can('distributor_prices') && is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart_total = $cart->get_cart_contents_total(); // Cart total

    if ( $cart_total >= 3000.00 && $cart_total < 5000.00 )
        $percent = 15; // 15%
    elseif ( $cart_total >= 1500.00 && $cart_total < 3000.00 )
        $percent = 10; // 10%
    elseif ( $cart_total >= 750.00 && $cart_total < 1500.00 )
        $percent =  5; // 5%
    else
        $percent = 0;

    if ( $percent > 0 ) {
        $discount   = $cart_total * $percent / 100;
        $label_text = sprintf( __("Bulk Order Discount %s"), '('.$percent.'%)' );
        $cart->add_fee( $label_text, -$discount, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

**For multiple user roles** you will use `wp_get_current_user()` to get the current `WP_User` Object, and then you can get the `roles` property like:

```
$user       = wp_get_current_user();
$user_roles = $user->roles;  // An array of the user roles
```

Then you will replace in the code:

```
    // HERE we target other user roles than 'distributor_prices' (allowing guests)
    if ( current_user_can('distributor_prices') && is_user_logged_in() )
        return;
```

by:

```
    // HERE we target "wholesale_prices" and "wholesale_vat_exc" user roles (allowing guests)
    if ( ! array_intersect( wp_get_current_user()->roles, array('wholesale_prices', 'wholesale_vat_exc') && is_user_logged_in() )
        return;
```

Or

```
    // HERE we target "wholesale_prices" and "wholesale_vat_exc" user roles (allowing guests)
    if ( ! ( current_user_can('wholesale_prices') || current_user_can('wholesale_vat_exc') ) && is_user_logged_in() )
        return;
```

Comment: Thanks man! How to add multiple roles to this: `if ( ! current_user_can('wholesale_prices') )` ?

Comment: Ok, I think I found it:    `if ( ! current_user_can('wholesale_customer') && !current_user_can('wholesale_vat_exc') )`

Comment: After some time I realized that the above code is working just for registered user, how to include guest users? Here is the current code: `if ( ! array_intersect( wp_get_current_user()->roles, array('wholesale_customer', 'wholesale_vat_exc') ) )
        return;`

Comment: @HuseinYuseinov I have updated my answer code… Now it should allow guests too.

Comment: Much appreciated answer!